# How to clone code from multiple sources in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

My code is in TFS repository but due to some reason few files are in Sharepoint/MS Teams, how can we clone code from both the sources in the build definition.

**Get Sources** task is the default which clones the specified TFS repository, is there a way to add or edit this task to clone code from Sharepoint at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the Get Sources task to clone code from sharepoint.

However, you can use a [powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to download the files from the sharepoint.

For example, add a powershell task in your pipeline to run below inline scripts:

**Using WebClient**

```
$SharePointFile = "https://the.server/path/to/the/file.txt"
$Path = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\file.txt"

#User Information
$Username = "userName"
$Password = "password"

#Download Files
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($UserName, $Password)
$client.DownloadFile($SharePoint, $Path)
$client.Dispose()
```

**Using Invoke-WebRequest**

```
$User = "userName"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

$url = 'https://the.server/path/to/the/file.txt'
$outfile = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\file.txt"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outfile -Credential $Credential
```

Above script will download the file from your sharepoint server to the source code folder `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` on the agent machine (ie. `c:\agent_work\1\s`)

You can also use [SharePoint Pnp PowerShell Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) to download the files in powershell task. See [example](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-download-file-from-library-using-powershell.html) in this blog.